# Connecting a proxy to a Python script using the Telethon module

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, txt

I need to get the proxy from the proxy.txt file:

```
ip:port:username:password
```

and add to the code:

```
file = dbm_base()
api_id = int(file['api_id4'].decode())
api_hash = file['api_hash4'].decode()
client = TelegramClient('client4', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, 'ip', port, 'username', 'password'))#port without ''
```

I doing this:

```
with open('proxy.txt', 'r') as f:
    proxys = f.readline().split(":")

file = dbm_base()
api_id = int(file['api_id4'].decode())
api_hash = file['api_hash4'].decode()
s = socks.socksocket()
client = TelegramClient('client1', api_id, api_hash, proxy=s.set_proxy(socks.HTTP, f'{proxys[0]}', int(proxys[1]), f'{proxys[2]}', f'{proxys[3]}'))
```

But the proxy server does not connect to the script.

What did I do wrong and why is the proxy server not connecting?

Comment: You should better use MTPROTO proxy. Its officially supported by telegram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about HTTP proxy or others, but you can use MTPROTO proxy with super ease:

```py
server = 'firewall.firewall-gw.cam'           # TODO: proxy server or ip
port = 443                                    # TODO: set port, normally 443
secret = 'dd00000000000000000000000000000000' # TODO: set proxy secret, normally hex encoded

connection = connection.ConnectionTcpMTProxyRandomizedIntermediate # this mode supports most proxies
client = TelegramClient('client1', api_id, api_hash, connection=connection,proxy=(server, port, secret)))
```

MTPROXY can be took from [@ProxyMTProto](https://t.me/ProxyMTProto). (Note: Its open source [here](https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/MTProxy))

The problem with other public proxies is that, they expire frequently.

Learn more [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/signing-in.html#using-mtproto-proxies).